# MySQL Returning 3 joins of data doesnt work as expected

Tags: sql, mysql

Basically I am trying to return data from my client table where the first name and the last name match. I am also grabbing data from the business tables. However, I want to grab data from a third table (appointments), basically, I just want to see how many entries exist by the clientId. This table is called appointments.

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.ClientId, c.ClientToBusiness, 
    b.BusinessId, c.ClientFirstName, c.ClientLastName, 
    c.ClientPhoneNumber, c.ClientAddress, c.ClientAddress2, 
    b.BusinessName, b.BusinessAddress, b.BusinessAddress2, 
    b.BusinessCity, b.BusinessState, b.BusinessZip, 
    b.BusinessOwnerName, b.BusinessOwnerEmail, 
    b.BusinessOwnerPhoneNumber, c.ClientCity, c.ClientState, 
    c.ClientZip, c.DateCreated as ClientAddedDate  
from clients c 
    join clients c2 on upper(c.ClientFirstName)=upper(c2.ClientFirstName) AND upper(c.ClientLastName)=upper(c2.ClientLastName) 
    LEFT JOIN business b ON c2.ClientToBusiness=b.BusinessId
-- LEFT JOIN appointments a on c2.ClientToBusiness=a.BusinessId
where c.id != c2.id
    order by c.ClientFirstName
```

With this query, I grab two entries from my client table where the first name last name are the same. I also grab what business these clients belong to. I also want to find out what appointments they have in the appointment table. However, when I add the LEFT JOIN for appointments in, it will remove one of the results from the query and only shows me 1 result instead of both. What is the right way to write this query?

Use case: the admin will be able to remove the duplicate client they do not want, but then all of the appointment under that duplicate client will be moved to the client we are keeping.

Thanks!

The above query will result in the left side. When I do the below query, it results in the right.

```
$query = "SELECT c.id, c.ClientId, COUNT(a.id) as NumOfAppts, c.ClientToBusiness, b.BusinessId, c.ClientFirstName, c.ClientLastName, c.ClientPhoneNumber, c.ClientAddress, c.ClientAddress2, b.BusinessName, b.BusinessAddress, b.BusinessAddress2, b.BusinessCity,
b.BusinessState, b.BusinessZip, b.BusinessOwnerName, b.BusinessOwnerEmail, b.BusinessOwnerPhoneNumber, c.ClientCity, c.ClientState, c.ClientZip, c.DateCreated as ClientAddedDate  from clients c join clients c2
on upper(c.ClientFirstName)=upper(c2.ClientFirstName) AND upper(c.ClientLastName)=upper(c2.ClientLastName) 
LEFT JOIN business b ON c2.ClientToBusiness=b.BusinessId
LEFT JOIN appointments a on b.BusinessId=a.BusinessId
where c.id != c2.id
order by c.ClientFirstName";
```

[image]

Comment: Your query should return same or more rows with the third left join. Is this the exact query you're using. BTW, looks like appointments and business are not linked with each other so you'll simply get all possible combinations of business and appointments for `c2`.

Comment: The query is slightly different, let me update my question.

Comment: @SalmanA I took the advise you had and LEFT JOIN appoints where b.BID=a.BID. I also added COUNT(a.id) as NumOfAppts. You can see the results. I still want to see both entries, but it will display how many appts they have in the result.

Comment: select from  c join  c2..where c.id != c2.id looks logically flawed it works where there are 2 and returns 2 rows , but for 3 returns 6 rows  and for  4 12 rows.

Comment: @letsCode Now that you posted the actual query (which contains a `count(*)`) I want to remind you that if you put an aggregate function in select clause and do not add a group by clause the result is always one row no matter how many rows matched (or 0 rows if there was no match). Also, such queries are invalid in proper RDBMS but MySQL allows it under old settings. Post another question, with minimal query + data and expected result. The solution from top of my mind is to use the `count` inside a subquery inside select clause.